# Resource (ip) online but not responding to connection attempts

Tags: kubernetes

I installed an app via my VPS with minikube and my code is functional (everything is perfect) but I have a problem deploying it on a browser (online resource i.e. the IP does not respond to attempts connection)

I configured the firewall to allow incoming connections on this port.

Comment: Not sure your /etc/hosts file you have added IP or not and how you are exposing service with loadbalancer service or ingress ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.